# How to draw shapes with color gradients and different opacities?

Tags: java

I have used transparency to paint shapes using Graphics.drawXXX methods but they always were solid colors, and now I need something a bit different:

I need to draw a shape on my component with a color gradient that goes from an absolutely opaque black color to an absolutely transparent black color.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the two `Color` objects (constructed using the 4 `int` form) for the `GradientPaint`.
2. Set that paint to the `Graphics` obtained from an image declared to support transparency (e.g. `TYPE_INT_ARGB`).
3. Paint (probably using one of the 'fill' methods).

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be such a stupid question. I missed the 4 int constructor. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note for future readers: The 4 int constructor didn't work for me, the 4 float constructor did. Color c = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

Comment: *"The 4 int constructor didn't work for me.."*  Huhh.  That is odd.  I always use the int values and have not had trouble with transparent colors.  Note that the 'last 2 ints' should be 0 (fully transparent) & 255 (fully opaque).